# Change obligatory Version field in Testlink Issue Tracker

Tags: jira-rest-api, testlink

Working on integrating Testlink 1.9.16 with Jira.
I need to change the obligatory status on the Version field in the Issue tracker popup window (since the version is not used and there are no entries for it).
Field in question is shown in the screenshot below (ignore the varDump on top of the page, part of debugging).
Which of the code or classes could be handling this? Would it be PHP or javascript (I suspect JS). Alternatively, can I disable that field (the other 3 have to stay).
[Create Issue window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JTcp.png)